# Spawn a DialogFragment while keeping focus on an outside view

Tags: android, webview

As this post relates to closed source software, I'm afraid I can't share any code snipplets... sorry about that!

---

#### Background

What I am trying to accomplish is to replace native autocomplete suggestions with a webview inside of an autocomplete dropdown. Now that could've been implemented in a few ways:

1. Implement Webview inside of a popup which anchors to the bottom of a EditText.
2. Use a vertical linearLayout which contains the searchEntry and the autocomplete webview with clipping disabled.
3. Implement the searchEntry as a standalone activity/fragment.
4. Commit the webview fragment inside of a DialogFragment.

---

#### Blockers

For reasons specific to internal frameworks and policy, I have resorted to option 4 for the following reasons:

Option 1 - The webview I'm using comes with a WebviewFragment controller that's required to interact with the rest of the application. As a result I must commit the fragment inside of the popupWindow. I've found no way to do this as the popup is detached.

Option 2 - I have to disable clipping in views higher in the hierarchy which is owned by other teams. I would like to avoid a lengthy review process if possible. This may also impact other teams in unforeseen ways.

Option 3 - The view I'm creating is created in another package higher up in the hierarchy, again owned by another team, and consumed by many more. The view implements an interface which has many custom controllers that I cannot easily replace in a standalone activity or fragment.

---

#### Option 4

I've opted to go with option 4, but I'm running into a major issue: I can't seem to set the focus to the EditText outside of the DialogFragment after the DialogFragment is spawned. This results in the UI looking odd, and we're not able to properly set the EditText value.

---

#### My Question

Is there a better solution for this use case? Is there an option worth revisiting?